# ui-grid grouping: ordering by aggregated value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

Let's say i have array of people:

```
[
  {name: 'Vasily', age: 18, salary: 5},
  {name: 'Vasily', age: 25, salary: 10},
  {name: 'Vasily', age: 30, salary: 15},
  {name: 'Ivan'  , age: 18, salary: 6},
  {name: 'Ivan'  , age: 25, salary: 9},
  .......
]
```

Each person has several rows in this array showing their salaries in different moments of life.

I want to `group by name` and `aggregate salary` and then **sort by** that **aggregated salary**. So that if i sort by aggregated salary descending i could see who earned more.

[Here is plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/08NnujJTZewUYW35umL5?p=preview) with what i got at this moment. This sorts by salary inside each group and i want to sort by salary globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found out the way. I had to use `ui-tree-view` instead.
Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dJmfEJKAdqlGbEdN)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [angular datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withColumnFilter) they allow to order records based on multiple columns, so you can add your data set and everything will be done for you.

Regarding Grid-UI, I found this [doc](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/320_complex_grouping) and from what i am seeing i don't think it's possible to sort while you are grouping data by a different column.
I think you need to remove the grouping in order it to work.

Comment: thx for your quick reply, i added plunker, plz check if you can help with it